# How does this SQLi statement work?

Tags: sql-injection, mysql

Hey i'm trying the hacker101 CTF's im still pretty new at this stuff

The CTF answer to the flag i'm trying to understand is https://github.com/testerting/hacker101-ctf/tree/master/micro-cms_v2/flag0

The important part of the error you get when you put a single `'` in the username field
`if cur.execute('SELECT password FROM admins WHERE username=\'%s\'' % request.form['username'].replace('%', '%%')) == 0:`

The solution to the flag is to input this into a username field

```
' UNION SELECT '123' AS password#
```

This is the statement I don't understand. I googled "SQL AS keyword" and I got something saying something along these lines, "The as keyword is a alias for a column or table" But `'123'` is a string, right? I got then got fustrated and moved on to the other thing I don't understand about the statement, the # at the end of password. I then also googled the "sql pound symbol" and I got it was referencing a temp table, which again, I don't really get..

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SQL statement executed when you input `' UNION SELECT '123' AS password#` is:

```
SELECT password FROM admins WHERE username='' UNION SELECT '123' AS password#'
```

The pound sign is there so that the closing `'` from the original format string, which is now trailing at the end of the query, does not tigger a syntax error. This is a MySQL extension to the SQL language and will not work on many other SQL servers, e.g., on PostgreSQL. There the standard `--` is required.

The `UNION` keyword combines the result sets from two or more `SELECT` statements (by chaining them with `UNION` keywords). The first result, that from `SELECT password FROM admins WHERE username=''`, is empty unless there is a row with an empty (but not `NULL`) username. The second one is the result set from `SELECT '123' AS password`, which is a single-row table with a single column called `password`. The `AS password` is not strictly necessary since MySQL uses the column names from the first statement when performing the union.

In SQL, selecting constants like `'123'` or constant expressions like `LENGTH('123')` replicates their value over the rows of the result set. If there is nothing in the query that produces more than one row, the result contains a single row.

Comment: Thank you for the in depth explanation, what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

In MySQL, `#` represents the start of a comment. This means the rest of the line will not be parsed as SQL. This is a common technique in SQL injection to force the trailing SQL after the injected SQL to be ignored.

In this case, by putting `' UNION SELECT '123' AS password#` in the username field, it makes the command that's executed:

```
SELECT password FROM admins WHERE username='' UNION SELECT '123' AS password
```

This returns a row with '123' as the password column (regardless of the username provided), allowing you to log in with any username and the password '123'.